# no match for operator '=' (std::array<T, 3> and std::initializer_list<T>)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

I have a template `vec<T>` class for math vectors with constant length is equal to 3.
It looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class vec{
public:
    vec() { /**/ }

    vec(std::initializer_list<T> list) { /**/ }

private:
    std::array<T, 3> data;
};
```

I know, that it is possible to initialize `std::array` with an `std::initializer_list` in such a way:

```cpp
std::array<int, 3> a = {1, 2, 3};
```

So I would like to have a constructor with an `std::initializer_list` to initialize my vector like this:

```cpp
vec<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
```

I also have a solution for this: just iterate through `std::initializer_list` elements and write to `data`:

```cpp
vec(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
        data[i++] = *it;
    }
}
```

I tried to make constructor look like this (because of `std::array` has a constructor with `std::initializer_list`):

```cpp
vec(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
    data = list;
}
```

But when I try to compile a program, the error occurs:

```sh
no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::array<int, 3>’ and ‘std::initializer_list<int>)’
```

What's the problem here? Why can't I initialize `std::array` with initializer list in such a way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can't I initialize `std::array` with initializer list in such a way?

Braced-init-list and [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) are not the same thing. (Even `std::initializer_list` could be constructed from braced-init-list.) `std::array` is an aggregate and could be [aggregate-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) or assigned by braced-init-list as

```
std::array<int, 3> a = {1, 2, 3};
a = {4, 5, 6}; // convert {4, 5, 6} to std::array then assign to a
```

Note that both `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}` are braced-init-list but not `std::initializer_list`.

`std::array` can't be initialized (or assigned) from an `std::initializer_list`; its constructors and assignment operator are [implicitly-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array#Implicitly-defined_member_functions) and doesn't have such constructor or assignment operator taking `std::initializer_list`.

```
std::initializer_list<int> l = {1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 3> a = l; // doesn't work
a = l;                    // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4):

As a possible work-around, you could add a constructor overload taking a `std::array` instead, and use a constructor initializer list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`) to initialize `data`:

```
vec(std::array<T, 3> const& list)
    : data{ list }
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `std::initializer_list` as a container class that works specifically for ctor parameters with the `obj{args...}` syntax.

Underneath, it contains a temporary c-array, with `size()` and pointer to `begin()` and `end()`. And there isn't a implicit conversion between `std::initializer_list` to `std::array`.

Other posts already mentioned ways of doing it, another way you could do is

```
std::copy(list.begin(), list.begin() + data.size(), data.begin());
```

This would work even if your `list.size()` is larger than `data.size()`.

Do note that if `list.size()` is smaller than `data.size()`, anything pass beyond `list.size()` would be default initialized, which would cause ub for scalar types.